# Apache Flink - Run same job multiple times for multi-tenant applications

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-flink, apache-storm, flink-streaming

We have a multi-tenant application where we maintain message queue for each tenant. We have implemented a Flink job to process the stream data from the message queues. Basically each of the message queue is a source in the Flink job. Is this the recommended way to do so? Or is it ok to run the same job (with one source) multiple times based on the number of tenants? We expect that the each of the tenants will produce data in different volumes. Will there be any scalability advantages in the multi job approach?

Approaches
1: Single job with multiple sources
2. Run duplicate of same job each with one source each

I think these approaches suits to Storm, Spark or any other streaming platforms.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance-wise approach 1) has the greatest potential. Resources are better utilized for the different sources. Since it's different sources, the optimization potential of the query itself is limited though.

However, if we really talk multi-tenant, I'd go with the second approach. You can assign much more fine-grain rights to the application (e.g., which Kafka topic can be consumed, to which S3 bucket to write). Since most application developer tend to develop GDPR compliant workflows (even though the current countries might not be affected), I'd go this route to stay on the safe side. This approach also has the advantage that you don't need to restart the jobs for everyone if you add/remove a certain tenant.